# How to convert a folder into a single file in android

Tags: android

I want to convert a folder which contains pics and videos into a single file.
I knew about zipping the file but i don't want to waste the mobile battery as the program gonna takes place in background.
So I need the folder to be converted into single file and it should not suck the RAM and battery much.
Thus the folder needs to be converted into single file without any disturbance occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to convert a folder which contains pics and videos into a single file

The only thing built into Android for this would be to ZIP up the files, using the `java.util.zip` classes. You are welcome to find yourself a library that can implement other similar algorithms (e.g., tar).

> but i don't want to waste the mobile battery as the program gonna takes place in background

If your concern is the compression aspect of a ZIP file, choose compression level 0 (i.e., `setMethod()` on `ZipEntry` with a value of `STORED`), which just concatenates the files together.

> I need the folder to be converted into single file and it should not suck the RAM and battery much

Any attempt to "convert a folder... into a single file" will have some impact on RAM and battery, because disk I/O is involved. Concatenating the files together is about as cheap as you'll get.

Comment: yeah ok, i accept your suggestion and i tried in your way, I succeed in zipping the files stored in internal or external storage however i am unable to zip the folder located in cache (getCacheDir()). It just creates a empty zip file(bad formatted zip file). I permitted to read internal files but still it happens....what i have to do now to zip the cache files?

Comment: @Ramprabhu: There should be no different in zipping files from `getCacheDir()` than anywhere else. You may wish to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you post the code that you are using to create the ZIP archive.